# Express Product of an Arithmetic Sequence in Terms of Factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, arithmetic-progressions

How do you express the product of $5*8*11*14$ $*$ $...$ in terms of factorials that are functions of $n$,  where $n$ stands for the number of terms in the product? Notice that the terms of the product form an arithmetic sequence, in which the $i$th term of the sequence is $3i+2$.

For $n=1$ the product is $5$.

For $n=2$ the product is $5*8$.

For $n=3$ the product is $5*8*11$.

For $n=4$ the product is $5*8*11*14$.

And so on...

Comment: I don't understand how your sequence is constructed. What you've written looks like an infinite product of integers. Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Okay, I've made some edits. I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: According to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A034000), they are one half of triple factorial numbers.

Comment: @Rohan Post as an answer?

Comment: The best I can offer is $$\frac{\Gamma(n+5/3)}{\Gamma(5/3)}\,3^n,$$ where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), an extension of factorials. But I don't think you'll like it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A034000), the nth term of the sequence of products $5\times 8 \times 11...$ are one half of the triple factorial numbers.

For more information on multifactorials, you may want to check out this [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials) section.

Comment: Is there any way to express the product in terms of the ordinary factorial?

Comment: See the wiki page. It states that $$n! = n!!! \times (n-1)!!! \times (n-2)!!!,  n\geq2$$

Comment: Well that's pretty obvious. I want $n!!!=f(n!)$.

Comment: @TheRiddler See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Generalizations) also.

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
$\prod_{k=1}^n (ak+b)
=a^n \prod_{k=1}^n (k+b/a)
=a^n\dfrac{Γ(n + b/a + 1)}{Γ(b/a + 1)}
$.

This is
$a=3, b=2$
so the $n$-th term is
$\prod_{k=1}^n (3k+2)
=3^n\dfrac{Γ(n + 5/3)}{Γ(5/3)}
$.